# Customise the URL for an asset

Tags: assets, url, siteurl

I need to prepend a URL to the beginning of an asset URL in order to track stats for a podcast via Blubrry.

What are the options?

Specifically I need to drop the https that would appear in my URL by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work with Blubrry specifically, but you can use it to get the data into Google Analytics for things that aren't normally trackable: [Instant Analytics](https://github.com/nystudio107/instantanalytics)

Check out the [Tracking RSS Feeds](https://github.com/nystudio107/instantanalytics#tracking-rss-feeds) section.